# Org Agenda Query

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-ql

I want to reproduce the result of the in-built Agenda view, yet add some further elements to it (using Org QL). I do not want to use block agendas, since they looks ugly. Instead, I want to return a larger result set and then group it using `org-super-agenda-groups`.

So my question is: What query (in traditional form, as applicable in `org-agenda-custom-commands`, or maybe even as it can be used by `org-ql` ) would replicate the exact result set returned by the agenda command?